# Selecting different keys based on success of failure of curl request

Tags: jq

I have the following output from a curl request which can differ based on success / failure of the request

Success:

```
{
  "name": "appId (xxxxx-xxx-1234)",
  "sent": 7939246,
  "received": 6673490,
  "details": [
    {
      "timestamp": "20180201000041",
      "sentbytes": 1805,
      "receivedbytes": 1485
    }
]}
```

Failure:

```
{
  "error": "Not found"
}
```

Can someone let me know how to check whether sent or error exists. I have tried

```
jq '. | select (.error | .sent)
```

but that does not seem to be the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close.

```
jq '. | select(.error or .sent)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter (no need for additional pipes):

```
jq '.sent or .error'
```

The output:

```
true
```

Comment: Though I use jq -r 'select (.error or .sent)', I am getting the output as 
{
"error": "Not Found"
}

Is there a way to get just the raw output (which I get when i use jq -r '.error') as I want to get the values for further processing